# Using list map with lambda function for str Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I used to use an apply function to compare column names to a valid dictionary i managed this with a list in a list but i need to make it more dynamic and not set on a fixed list of column names so I am finding the column names first and removing the ones that are not found

```
import pandas as pd

filename='template'
 
data= [['','','','','','','','Auto','','','','','']]

df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['first','last','state','lang','country','company','email','industry',
                                'system','acct','segment','existing','permission'])

valid= {'industry': ['Automotive'],
        'SME Vertical': ['Agriculture'],
        'system': ['Access'],
        'acct': ['Commercial']}

errors= {}
errors[filename]={}

col_list=[col for col in df]
key=list(valid.keys())
key = [k for k in valid if k in col_list]
        
mask = list(map(lambda c: c in (valid[c]),key))
key(mask|key(' ')).stack()
for err_i, (r, v) in enumerate(key(mask|key(' ')).stack().iteritems()):
    errors[filename][err_i] = {"row": r[0],
                               "column": r[1],
                               "message": v + " is invalid check column " + r[1] + ' and replace with a standard value'}
```

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

To clarify I had to use map instead of apply since I need to remove variable names in valid that are not in the df the real df is an excel template and some of the variable are missing based on what template is being used so i want the code to be more dynamic.

**I do not understand why I am getting this error, can someone explain to me how to correct this attribute error?**

desired output in the errors dictionary:

```
{"Template": {"0": {"row": 0, "column": "industry", "message": "Auto is invalid check column industry and replace with a standard value"}}}
```

I am trying to get the code to iterate through each row and match the values in the rows to the values in valid and if they dont match then send the error message to the dictionary 'errors'. This is why i am only testing the column names that are also found in valid hence this pieces of code

```
col_list=[col for col in df]
key=list(valid.keys())
key = [k for k in valid if k in col_list]
```

Comment: Here `key(mask | key(' ')).stack()` you are trying to "call" the list `key()` twice

Comment: @АлексейР so if i just call key(mask).stack() that would work?

Comment: This won't help, because the list cannot be called in any way, it's not a function. Could you please explain with examples what exactly you are trying to solve?

Comment: @АлексейР I added more explanation and a desire output